# Using PostgreSQL 12.12 pg_ commands in Ubuntu 20.04 not working

Tags: software-installation, postgresql, pg

I've installed PostGreSQL 12.12 with:

```
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev
```

But I'm seeing errors with `pg_` commands.  For example, this is the error when trying to setup replication:

```
postgres-# pg_create_physical_replication_slot wallinfo, immediately_reserve true, temporary true;  
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_create_physical_replication_slot"

LINE 1: pg_create_physical_replication_slot wallinfo, immediately_re...  
       ^  
The error is the first letter p from pg_
```

What can I do to enable the pg_ commands.

I've checked:

```
> whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby2.7 /usr/bin/ruby /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby /usr/lib/ruby /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz
```

But I'm still encounter errors when using the `pg_` commands in psql.

Comment: Replication is typically configured by editing the `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` files. Are you trying to build a very specific sort of replication? 

Comment: postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf is needed for communication, to setup the WAL files I need to configure the database to make things possible

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing now. Those `pg_` objects are functions, so you need to wrap them in a `SELECT`. For example: `SELECT * FROM pg_create_physical_replication_slot('standby1_slot');`

Comment: @matigo  the official command is pg_create_physical_replication_slot(slot_name name [, immediately_reserve boolean, temporary boolean])  as input I changed the line to pg_create_physical_replication_slot (slot_name wallinfo, immediately_reserve true, temporary true);  stil the error point to the p from pg_

Comment: The answer is that pg_create is not present in the /usr/lib/postgresql/12/main directory and therefore can't be executed.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that pg_create is not present in the /usr/lib/postgresql/12/main directory and therefore can't be executed.